# Do you want to view only the webpage content.... - https

Tags: asp.net, https

while implementing hhtps, is there a way not to show the message "Do you want to view only the webpage content that was delivered securely?" and force the answer to "no" as it will mess up with my css and javascript .

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is implemented by the browser process, not the transport mechanism. There are plenty of custom implementations that would not show that warning, but most commonly available browsers will as it represents a potential security hole in the SSL process.

Essentially its the browser warning you that it only got part of the content from an SSL connection, and there is no way for you the end user to directly tell which page elements are from the trusted (i.e. SSL connected) host and which are from untrusted hosts.

If you want to avoid this, either consider placing your CSS/javascript in the pages directly, or limit your SSL to only specific pages which do not include those resources.

Comment: How do i limit the SSL on resources.. the following is the error:
'ASP.NET Ajax client-side framework failed to load'.

Answer (score 2):

you may need to serve all the page elements, including the css and javascript from the SSL server.

Also see [Dealing with HTTP content in HTTPS pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3011222/dealing-with-http-content-in-https-pages)

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps to turn this off, but as everything you with security you must weight the risks.

1. Navigate to Tools-> Internet Options-> Security
2. Select the "Security Tab"
3. Click the "Custom Level" button at the bottom
4. In the "Miscellaneous" section change "Display mixed content" to Enable
5. Then click the "OK" button

Fissh