# What's the advantage of protocol-less urls over https by default?

Tags: html, https

As the title states, why should I use `//` instead of `https`? I understand that on an `https` page you shouldn't load resources over `http`, but AFAIK there is no downside of loading your resources over `https` when the page itself is loaded over `http`. 
So what are the advantages of using `//` over `https`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8465383/loading-http-content-on-https-website

Comment: @NickR That's the reverse question. I fully understand why you shouldn't load `http` resources on a `https` site, but I don't understand what's wrong with loading `https` resources on a `http` site.

Comment: @Tiddo Speed? Establishing an HTTPS connection (certificate exchange) to get one small script file is probably a waste of time. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use of https may be less efficient, since it involves encryption. A resource might reside on a web server that does not support https requests.

Comment: If a webserver doesn't support `https` then you can't use `//` as well, since that'll break if your page is served over `https`. Is performance the only problem?

Comment: If a server does not support https, you can still use `//` to the extent that the referring page itself uses http. But admittedly it is then better to use explicit `http://`. I made this point to address the note “ere is no downside of loading your resources over https when the page itself is loaded over http”.

Comment: Oh I get it now, I was thinking about loading external resources from an http-only server while the page itself is served over `https`. But for resources loaded from the same server this would of course work just fine. So basically the main reason to use `//` over `https` (besides performance) is when you don't know in advance if the server the website is going to run on supports https, such that it can fallback to `http` when `ssl` is disabled, right?

Comment: @Tiddo, well, yes. I suppose a common scenario is an e-commerce site that uses http for normal browsing but switches to https when confidential information is requested from the user. Using `//` URLs, you can use the same code in both phases. The alternative would be to use https throughout, and in a high-traffic site, the overhead might matter.