# Images are not loaded over https, but nothing error is displayed

Tags: php, image, .htaccess, ssl, https

I have problem with setup SSL on my server. When images are loaded over HTTP, everything works fine. On http protocol (so path is http://domain.com/images/x.png) is OK, but when I rewrite on protocol https, the images are not displayed.

I not getting response 404 Not found, but normally 200 OK. But every image is white.

[White image loaded over https](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qp5sh.png)

Can you help me please? Thanks!

Comment: You cannot load HTTP images in HTTPS page. Refer this http://stackoverflow.com/a/8465400/6374322

Comment: But you can use this trick to do that so refer this http://stackoverflow.com/a/3042738/6374322

Comment: I load images over https! I have this URL https://example.com/images/xx.png