# Cross-Origin Request Headers(CORS) with PHP headers

Tags: php, javascript, xmlhttprequest, cors

I have a simple PHP script that I am attempting a cross-domain CORS request:

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *");
...
```

Yet I still get the error:

> Request header field `X-Requested-With` is not allowed by `Access-Control-Allow-Headers`

Anything I'm missing?

Answer (score 78, accepted):

`Access-Control-Allow-Headers` does not allow `*` as accepted value, see the Mozilla Documentation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Headers).

Instead of the asterisk, you should send the accepted headers (first `X-Requested-With` as the error says).

### Update:

`*` is now accepted is `Access-Control-Allow-Headers`.

According to [MDN Web Docs 2021](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Headers):

> The value `*` only counts as a special wildcard value for requests without credentials (requests without HTTP cookies or HTTP authentication information). In requests with credentials, it is treated as the literal header name `*` without special semantics. Note that the Authorization header can't be wildcarded and always needs to be listed explicitly.

Comment: As of 2021, it looks like `*` is now accepted as per the MDN docs.

Answer (score 422):

Handling CORS requests properly is a tad more involved.  Here is a function that will respond more fully (and properly).

```
/**
 *  An example CORS-compliant method.  It will allow any GET, POST, or OPTIONS requests from any
 *  origin.
 *
 *  In a production environment, you probably want to be more restrictive, but this gives you
 *  the general idea of what is involved.  For the nitty-gritty low-down, read:
 *
 *  - https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTTP_access_control
 *  - https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#http-cors-protocol
 *
 */
function cors() {
    
    // Allow from any origin
    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'])) {
        // Decide if the origin in $_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'] is one
        // you want to allow, and if so:
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: {$_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']}");
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
        header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 86400');    // cache for 1 day
    }
    
    // Access-Control headers are received during OPTIONS requests
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'OPTIONS') {
        
        if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_METHOD']))
            // may also be using PUT, PATCH, HEAD etc
            header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS");
        
        if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']))
            header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: {$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']}");
    
        exit(0);
    }
    
    echo "You have CORS!";
}
```

### Security Notes

> **Check the HTTP_ORIGIN header against a list of approved origins.**

If the origin isn't approved, then you should deny the request.

Please read the spec.

### TL;DR

When a browser wants to execute a cross-site request it first confirms that this is okay with a "pre-flight" request to the URL.  By allowing CORS you are telling the browser that responses from this URL can be shared with other domains.

CORS does not protect your server.  CORS attempts to protect your users by telling browsers what the restrictions should be on sharing responses with other domains.  Normally this kind of sharing is utterly forbidden, so CORS is a way to poke a hole in the browser's normal security policy.  These holes should be as small as possible, so always check the HTTP_ORIGIN against some kind of internal list.

**There are some dangers here**, especially if the data the URL serves up is normally protected.  You are effectively allowing browser content that originated on some other server to read (and possibly manipulate) data on your server.

If you are going to use CORS, please read the protocol carefully (it is quite small) and try to understand what you're doing.  A reference URL is given in the code sample for that purpose.

#### Header security

It has been observed that the HTTP_ORIGIN header is insecure, and that is true.  In fact, all HTTP headers are insecure to varying meanings of the term.  Unless a header includes a verifiable signature/hmac, or the whole conversation is authenticated via TLS, headers are just "something the browser has told me".

In this case, the browser is saying "an object from domain X wants to get a response from this URL.  Is that okay?"  The point of CORS is to be able to answer, "yes I'll allow that".

Comment: Note that sending the HTTP Origin value back as the allowed origin will allow anyone to send requests to you with cookies, thus potentially stealing a session from a user who logged into your site then viewed an attacker's page.  You either want to send '*' (which will disallow cookies thus preventing session stealing) or the specific domains for which you want the site to work.

Comment: Agreed.  In practice you probably wouldn't allow just any old domain to use your CORS service, you would restrict it to some set that you decided to trust.

Comment: FYI, this solution only worked for me in a `Linux server`, in `IIS` for some reason just didn't work, I dont know if its my hosting or just it's not suitable for `IIS`

Comment: This solution worked flawlessly in my PHP 5.6.2 at backend, and  AngularJS 1.3.12 at frontend.

Comment: The only that's truly work!.. Just change Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * TO Access-Control-Allow-Origin: {$_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']}

Comment: This isn't working for me. Do you have any sample for a working CORS server php script that can be ajax-requested, in working condition on the web? If so, please post the link here. Nothing seems to be working for me :(

Comment: THANKS !! What an absurd waste of time it took to finally find this, and test it like so many other solutions up here, and get the fine surprise "I am done with GD Coors !!

Comment: By unconditionally allowing any origin with `ACAC: true`, you're essentially throwing the Same-Origin Policy out the window. This answer is terrible advice from a security point of view, and it should be downvoted to oblivion.

Comment: Downvoted for using `$_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']`. This is a huge secury risk.

Comment: It is true that `$_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN]` is not "secure" in the sense that your app has no way of verifying the true origin of the request.  However, it is the **browser's** job to protect this header.  Your app is not trying to prevent people from various orgs from using it.  Rather, your app is confirming to the browser that cross-site requests from certain domains are acceptable at this URL.

Comment: my $_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'] is "defined but empty" (???)

Comment: @slashingweapon _it is the browser's job to protect [the `Origin`] header._ Browsers do a fine job at that, and yet your answer remains terrible security advice because server developers who follow it will expose their users to cross-origin attacks. You should really read https://portswigger.net/research/exploiting-cors-misconfigurations-for-bitcoins-and-bounties or watch https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wgkj4ZgxI4c and then amend your question accordingly.

Comment: @dmuensterer, you know what else is a huge security risk? relying on CORS on your server to block cross origin. I can write a program to send whatever `http_origin` (or in fact any http or https headers) that pleases your server and get information that I want from anywhere I like. The only use case that I see is reducing amateur hackers that are trying to get data out of your server.

Comment: @AaA I totally agree. But that wasn't the question here.

Comment: @slashingweapon I really like the additional comment you made to your answer regarding HTTP_ORIGIN. Thanks.

Answer (score 119):

I got the same error, and fixed it with the following PHP in my back-end script:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST');

header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With");
```

Comment: should these three lines added in top of PHP file ? Like

<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With");

Comment: I think you need to also allow OPTIONS in the Access-Control-Allow-Methods

Answer (score 51):

Many description internet-wide don't mention that specifying `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is not enough. Here is a complete example that works for me:

```
<?php
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'OPTIONS') {
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, DELETE, PUT, PATCH, OPTIONS');
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: token, Content-Type');
        header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 1728000');
        header('Content-Length: 0');
        header('Content-Type: text/plain');
        die();
    }

    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
    header('Content-Type: application/json');

    $ret = [
        'result' => 'OK',
    ];
    print json_encode($ret);
```

Comment: Please explain why it isn't enough and what minimal  example *is* enough.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't remember exactly and I have no time now to investigate it again but, as much as I remember, there were some basic assumptions from the webserver's/browser's side which made it not working. This was the minimal code that worked for me.

Comment: if already sent in virtul host of apache ..then only this code work ..if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'OPTIONS') {
      
        die();
    }

Comment: Basically what it says here is that it *is* enough, just not if the request method is 'options'.

Answer (score 33):

If you want to create a CORS service from PHP, you can use this code as the first step in your file that handles the requests:

```
// Allow from any origin
if(isset($_SERVER["HTTP_ORIGIN"]))
{
    // You can decide if the origin in $_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'] is something you want to allow, or as we do here, just allow all
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: {$_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']}");
}
else
{
    //No HTTP_ORIGIN set, so we allow any. You can disallow if needed here
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
}

header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true");
header("Access-Control-Max-Age: 600");    // cache for 10 minutes

if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "OPTIONS")
{
    if (isset($_SERVER["HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_METHOD"]))
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT"); //Make sure you remove those you do not want to support

    if (isset($_SERVER["HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS"]))
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: {$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']}");

    //Just exit with 200 OK with the above headers for OPTIONS method
    exit(0);
}
//From here, handle the request as it is ok
```

Comment: This solves my issue - apparently my PHP webservice not able to entertain OPTIONS request properly - on which my Angular front end is relying upon prior to sending the POST request. Thanks!

Comment: This is the best solution

Answer (score 29):

I've simply managed to get dropzone and other plugin to work with this fix (angularjs + php backend)

```
 header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); 
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true");
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS');
    header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 1000');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, Content-Type, X-Auth-Token , Authorization');
```

add this in your upload.php or where you would send your request (for example if you have upload.html and you need to attach the files to upload.php, then copy and paste these 4 lines).
Also if you're using CORS plugins/addons in chrome/mozilla be sure to toggle them more than one time,in order for CORS to be enabled

Comment: do we need to allow Origin header? sounds weird

Answer (score 15):

This much code works down for me when using angular 4 as the client side and PHP as the server side.

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
```

Comment: Be careful while using '*' wildcard. Never open it unless that's what you really intend to do. As for testing your angular app specify http://localhost:4200 and it will work while still being safer.

Comment: Tested on LAMP Server running PHP 7.4.x

Comment: I was using Apache server and PHP backend language; I also fixed my problem with the same single line of code.

Answer (score 14):

CORS can become a headache, if we do not correctly understand its functioning. I use them in PHP and they work without problems. [reference here](https://www.w3.org/wiki/CORS_Enabled)

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true");
header("Access-Control-Max-Age: 1000");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Origin, Cache-Control, Pragma, Authorization, Accept, Accept-Encoding");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: PUT, POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE");
```

Comment: I have used this in Codeigniter 4.1.3 and it doest work

Answer (score 10):

this should work

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Origin, Cache-Control, Pragma, Authorization, Accept, Accept-Encoding");
```

Comment: This worked really well on VUE + XAMPP (PHP)

Answer (score 6):

I used these 5 headers and after that solved the cors error(backend: PHP, Frontend: VUE JS)

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS, post, get');
header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 3600');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, Content-Type, X-Auth-Token');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
```

Answer (score 2):

add this code in **.htaccess**

add custom authentication key's in header like app_key,auth_key..etc

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers: "customKey1,customKey2, headers, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization"
```