# Serving image's data string over HTTPS while URLs on HTTP

Tags: php, html, image

I am attempting to read an image file, as a base64 encoded string and output a data string when the connection uses HTTPS/SSL, and otherwise put out the URL in the IMG src attribute if it is only on HTTP. Here is my current code, however it does not work.

```
<?php 
function base64_encode_image($filename, $filetype) {
    if (($_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on") && $filename) {
        $file = "/home/content/61/9295861/html/resource/image$filename";
        $imgbinary = fread(fopen($file, "r"), filesize($file));
        return "data:image/$filetype;base64," . base64_encode($imgbinary);
    } else {
        return $filename;
    }
}
?>
<img src="<?php echo base64_encode_image('/resource/image/logo-96x72.png', 'png'); ?>" width="96" height="72" />
```

It outputs:

```
<img src="<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  fopen(/home/content/61/9295861/html/resource/image/resource/image/logo-96x72.png) [<a href='function.fopen'>function.fopen</a>]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in <b>/home/content/61/9295861/html/theme/latest/index.php</b> on line <b>5</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  filesize() [<a href='function.filesize'>function.filesize</a>]: stat failed for /home/content/61/9295861/html/resource/image/resource/image/logo-96x72.png in <b>/home/content/61/9295861/html/theme/latest/index.php</b> on line <b>5</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  fread() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in <b>/home/content/61/9295861/html/theme/latest/index.php</b> on line <b>5</b><br />
data:image/png;base64," width="96" height="72" />
```

Comment: See this post It might help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3011222/dealing-with-http-content-in-https-pages

Comment: Any reason you're doing this? embedding images as base64 completely eliminates any chance to cache the images - you wouldn't save anything on bandwidth or ssl/tcp overhead - you'd just increase your bill heavily.

Comment: updated the code a bit, maybe itll make more sense

Comment: also provided the error now, so itll make more sense, my apologies

Comment: why don't you use `$imgbinary = file_get_contents($file);`, also you read mode should be `"rb"` instead of `"r"`

Comment: Your path is repeated in the string, try `<img src="<?php echo base64_encode_image('/logo-96x72.png', 'png'); ?>" width="96" height="72" />`

Comment: <img src="<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  file_get_contents(/home/content/61/9295861/html/resource/image/resource/image/logo-96x72.png) [<a href='function.file-get-contents'>function.file-get-contents</a>]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in <b>/home/content/61/9295861/html/theme/latest/index.php</b> on line <b>5</b><br />
data:image/png;base64," width="96" height="72" />

Comment: `/html/resource/image/resource/image/...` is the right path?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have added the **/image/resource** directory twice to your URL which is resulting in a **file not found error**.

```
$file = "/home/content/61/9295861/html/resource/image$filename";
$filename = "/resource/image/logo-96x72.png"
```

So your File URL is `/home/content/61/9295861/html/resource/image/resource/image/logo-96x72.png`

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
<img src="<?php echo base64_encode_image('/resource/image/logo-96x72.png', 'png'); ?>" width="96" height="72" />
```

to

```
<img src="<?php echo base64_encode_image('logo-96x72.png', 'png'); ?>" width="96" height="72" />
```