# I can't use openweathermap API any longer on codepen because google chrome blocks mixed content

Tags: javascript, jquery, openweathermap

The API has to be HTTPS because codepen is HTTPS, but the API doesn't work on HTTPS, so I'm stuck, what can I do?

Here's the code:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
  if(navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(handleGetCurrentPosition, onError);
  }
  function handleGetCurrentPosition(location) {
    console.log(location.coords.longitude + " " + location.coords.latitude);
    $.getJSON("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=-0.5507657&lon=47.475692800000004&appid=c024988151d2439343bc4617141ac25d", function(result) {
      console.log("City: "+result.city.name + " Weather: "+ result.list[0].weather[0].description);
    });
  }
  function onError() {
    $('body').innerHTML = "";
    $('body').innerHTML = "<h1>Sorry, there was a technical problem. Please reload the page later.";
  }
});
```

and here's the error message:

jquery.min.js:4 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://codepen.io/Gochaia/pen/ZWVoYz' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=-0.5507657&lon=47.475692800000004&appid=c024988151d2439343bc4617141ac25d'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

thanks.

**UPDATE**

I found a solution, thanks to @AlexChance. Forecast.io API is hosted over SSL, so there is no more mixed content.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24845531/using-open-weather-map-which-is-http-only-through-an-https-website-and-not-get-m

Comment: You need API key to access open weather api

Comment: @prathamkesarkar I included the API key if you look closely.

Comment: @AlexChance Thanks for the link, I think I found a solution.