# Blocked loading mixed active content over http

Tags: php, https, http-headers, mixed-content

I'm running my website over `https` and I'm trying to call an API which is on http what did I try is :

`//api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather`
`http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather`

but didn't succeed can you please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

There does not appear to be HTTPS support for this API. From [this question](https://openweathermap.desk.com/customer/portal/questions/8166727-http-to-https) on the OpenWeatherMap forums,

> HTTPS is available only in Professional and Enterprise accounts. In Free account this feature is not available.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24845531/using-open-weather-map-which-is-http-only-through-an-https-website-and-not-get-m/37519546#37519546) from another SO post where the API call is made outside and served separately.