# Mixed Content errors with https

Tags: reactjs, github

I made a simple weather app using react. It was working well. But when I hosted it on Github, it gives the error and is not working properly. Do someone know how to resolve this error?

**Mixed Content: The page at '' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure resource ''. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.**

[my errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DmAcI.png)
[2nd screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qxs7N.png)

Comment: found a similar post https://stackoverflow.com/q/24845531/8705343

Answer (score 1):

To fix the error you need to make sure that all external resources are all running over HTTPS.

So in this instance, you just need to change the openweathermap.com resource to load from https rather than http. If you leave it as http, then it just won't get loaded and then you'll end up with a ton of js errors as the code wasn't loaded properly.

Answer (score -1):

use https instead of http as the protocol of your base url