# HTTPS image requests not terminated

Tags: google-chrome, https, cloudflare

I just switched my site to HTTPS using CloudFlare and there's a page on my site where there're a lot of images. In HTTP, when I click the link on the page, the images that aren't loaded yet are terminated and the browser starts to load the next page. But after I switched to HTTPS, the browser waits for all the images to load before loading next page. Is there a better solution than forcing all images to use HTTP?

Browser: Chrome 38.0.2125.8 (64-bit)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dealing with HTTP content in HTTPS pages](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3011222/dealing-with-http-content-in-https-pages)

Comment: No, these two questions are totally unrelated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I found the solution. All you need to do is to move the images to another domain.