# Joomla wrapper and ssl

Tags: .htaccess, ssl, joomla, https, wrapper

I have joomla site and i set ssl on it. In some pages i have wrapper that load some form from another server.
When i used http it worked normal but after https it load too long and at the end show times out. 
If i don not write any protocol in url and set

> Add protocol - Yes

that time page loading normal but form blocks by browser. 
[link to page](https://carzilla.az/ru/voditelyu/proverka-shtrafov)
What need to do load wrapper normal or how to exclude page from ssl

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dealing with HTTP content in HTTPS pages](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3011222/dealing-with-http-content-in-https-pages)

Comment: How is this different than your other question?

Answer (score 0):

You are calling http content inside your web. This is the console output:

> Mixed Content: The page at 'https://carzilla.az/ru/voditelyu/proverka-shtrafov' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure resource 'http://85.132.44.29/nex'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

Try changing http://85.132.44.29/nex to https://85.132.44.29/nex

Is maybe that your problem? This resource is blocked.

**EDIT** 
Anyway, when calling the https URL, has no service.. then I think you will not be able to open that URL in a HTTPS situation.

Comment: Of course i know why its not loading. I try to change http => https but nothing. How can i exclude that wrapper pages from https. Force that pages load http.

Comment: then maybe you should correct your question to talk about that. 
Check answers here  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3011222/dealing-with-http-content-in-https-pages

Comment: If i understand correctly there no way to load http content through https. But is it possivle to change wrapper page from https to http. All site will load https except some pages. How can i exclude com_wrapper or some menu from https? Mayby need add some code to htaccess?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a programming question, it is a site administration question.
WHen you make the wrapper menu link, simply go to the metadata tab and tell it to make the link "not secure."