# Javascript script for Chrome Console not working with https webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using a script to get specified contents of specific links on a webpage and it has worked fine before, but after the site changed to https, it has stopped working. 
The script is as follows:

```
    var URL = window.location.origin

var episodeLinks = $('table.listing a').map(function(i,el) { return $(el).attr('href'); });

$.ajaxSetup({async:false});
$.getScript("https://kissanime.com/Scripts/asp.js");

var login = "vergo777";
var api_key = "R_6a13f014b38f4f80a31cf7d80a7c18c7";
var long_url; 

var startEpisode; 
do {
    startEpisode = prompt("Enter episode number you want to start from");
    if(startEpisode <= 0 || startEpisode > episodeLinks.length) {
        alert("Episode number entered must be greater than 0 and lesser than total number of eps"); 
    } else {
        break; 
    }
} while(true); 

var endEpisode; 
do {
    endEpisode = prompt("Enter episode number you want to end at");
    if(endEpisode <= 0 || endEpisode > episodeLinks.length || endEpisode < startEpisode) {
        alert("Episode number entered must be greater than 0 and lesser than total number of eps");
    } else {
        break;
    }
} while(true); 
var videoQuality = prompt("Enter video quality you want to download. Example - '960x720.mp4' (without the quotes)"); 

var i; 
for (i = (episodeLinks.length - startEpisode); i >= (episodeLinks.length - endEpisode); i--) {
    jQuery.ajax({
         url:    URL + episodeLinks[i], 
         success: function(result) {
                    var $result = eval($(result));
                    var stringStart = result.search("var wra"); 
                    var stringEnd = result.search("document.write"); 
                    var javascriptToExecute = result.substring(stringStart, stringEnd);
                    eval(javascriptToExecute);

                    $("body").append('<div id="episode' + i + '" style="display: none;"></div>')
                    $('#episode' + i).append(wra); 

                    var downloadQualityOptions = $('#episode' + i + ' a').map(function(i,el) { return $(el); });
                    var j; 
                    for(j = 0; j < downloadQualityOptions.length; j++) {
                        if(videoQuality === downloadQualityOptions[j].html()) {
                            long_url = downloadQualityOptions[j].attr('href');
                            console.log(i); 
                            get_short_url(long_url, login, api_key);
                        }
                    }
                  },
         async:   false, 
         script:  true
    });       
}


function get_short_url(long_url, login, api_key)
{
    $.getJSON(
        "http://api.bitly.com/v3/shorten?callback=?", 
        { 
            "format": "json",
            "apiKey": api_key,
            "login": login,
            "longUrl": long_url, 
            async: true
        },
        function(response)
        {
            console.log(response.data.url);
        }
    ); 
}
```

I am getting the error: Uncaught ReferenceError: asp is not defined(…)

Any help is very appreciated, thank you!

Comment: if are requesting to a http link from a https website, browsers will block them.

Comment: read this if are do so http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3011222/dealing-with-http-content-in-https-pages