# Prevent unsecure HTTP requests

Tags: javascript, html, ssl, tumblr

I have a blog on tumblr, and I am trying out the website with SSL. Now with Chrome and possibly other browsers, any images and scripts that are not loaded using HTTPS are automatically blocked, and I lose the happy little green lock icon in the address bar. I am able to edit the HTML of the theme, however there are too many external scripts that are used to load images (and other scripts) to be able to weed out and fix every HTTP request. Obviously, I don't have access to the web server settings for tumblr.com or I could have easily configured HTTPS redirects or something.

I was wondering if there would be any way to prevent the HTML and other included scripts from making HTTP requests through the use of javascript. The website appears and functions just fine without the blocked elements, and I just want the lock icon to show my visitors that it's a safe website.

I have no intention of advertising my blog here, as I'm sure it is against the user policy on this forum. That being said, if it is helpful for troubleshooting reasons, I can post the link if requested.

Comment: Have you tried looking for the answer on SO? May be you are'nt the first person. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3011222/dealing-with-http-content-in-https-pages