# Convert external resource to https

Tags: php, https

My site is loading images from other sites and this is causing warnings when I implemented `HTTPS` instead of plain `HTTP`. I know why this is happening but I'm wondering how to correct.

Best solution I have seen is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3011222/dealing-with-http-content-in-https-pages?answertab=active#tab-top), but I don't understand how that works.

The poster suggests prepending `https://example.com/imageserver?url=` to the image url. This doesn't work. So what am I missing? What is `imageserver`?

I hope this makes sense, I'm not sure if I'm not just missing something obvious here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

imageserver could be a php script that fetch the image and display its contents.

a very simple example, not very safe

```
echo file_get_contents($_GET['url']);
```

The idea here is that the browser now gets the images from your secure server instead of the original non-https server.

Comment: I see. So when you say not very safe, why? I guess because the I would need to rewrite the file to ensure it is clean?

Comment: And should I be saving these files to my server or just displaying them from memory?

Comment: There are indeed no checks to make sure the file is clean. Maybe someone want to use this functionality to serve malware. That will be then be served through your server, so that's no good. And yes it is a good idea to save the files temporary (24 hours or so) on your server if you have enough space. That will save you some bandwidth.

Comment: Thanks I'm looking closer at how this is done today.