# Unable to call to API after deploying app to Heroku

Tags: reactjs, api, heroku, redux, mixed-content

I've made a weather app that makes an API call to freegeoip to locate your current location's coordinates, and then using those coordinates to connect to openweathermap API to fetch your current location's weather.

In development the app worked perfectly fine. But after deploying to Heroku, I seem to get what looks like a CORS error?

Console logs:

```
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://weather-react-drhectapus.herokuapp.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://freegeoip.net/json/'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

Link to [Heroku app](https://weather-react-drhectapus.herokuapp.com/)

**EDIT:**

Changing to `https` seems to work for the freegeoip API (`https://freegeoip.net/json/`), but doesn't work for the openweathermap API. This is the full console log I get:

```
GET https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?appid=95108d63b7f0cf597d80c6d17c8010e0&lat=49.25&lon=4.0333 net::ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED

bundle.js:16 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Network Error
    at e.exports (bundle.js:16)
    at XMLHttpRequest.d.onerror (bundle.js:16)

Google Maps API warning: NoApiKeys https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#no-api-keys

Google Maps API error: MissingKeyMapError https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#missing-key-map-error
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change API endpoint to use `https` instead of `http`.

`https://freegeoip.net/json/` works well ;)

**Update**
Your updated question contains one more request. Unfortunately, `api.openweathermap.org` is not available over HTTPS. Thus, you need to reach it thru proxy under your control and forward response to your client. For more info, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3011222/dealing-with-http-content-in-https-pages)

Comment: works for the freegeoip API, but not for the openweathermap one :(

Answer (score 0):

If you apply this middleware it should start working correctly

```
  app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    if (req.headers['x-forwarded-proto'] === 'https') {
      res.redirect('http://' + req.hostname + req.url);
    } else {
      next();
    }
  });
```