# Serving HTTP images over HTTPS

Tags: php, html, http, https

Alright so I've got a bunch of images on Rackspace now the problem is that they are all absolutely HTTP and I am changing my domain to HTTPS

Issue is quite simple, I am getting bunch of warnings for serving images from insecure server, I tried doing the "basic" method of just changing images URL from HTTP to HTTPS but of course they werent served on the website, what can I do regarding this? I need to serve thousands of images over HTTPS instead of HTTP

Image sample URL
http://c105344.r44.cf3.rackcdn.com/thumbnail/ae3e273e660f50a91a773a9c87f42c45.jpg

Comment: Get an SSL certificate onto your Rackspace server and serve them over HTTPS. Information seems to be here on the hows and how much's - https://support.rackspace.com/how-to/rackspace-cdn-secure-delivery-options/

Comment: Sending requests over https needs more traffic and Rackspace wants you to pay for this. If you don't want to pay you can use an https-proxy, but performance is reduced by doing this.

Comment: @mimo is there any sort of tutorial on it (https proxy)? Traffic aint a problem really

Comment: @TomislavNikolic you can install a script on your website that outputs all images like `https://mypage.com/proxy.php?url?http://c105344.r44.cf3.rackcdn.com/thumbnail/ae3e273e660f50a91a773a9c87f42c45.jpg`. The script will load the content of the given url and print it out with your domain that is secured by https

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dealing with HTTP content in HTTPS pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3011222/dealing-with-http-content-in-https-pages)